# SKCamera Node not adjusting in-game when I move it in the editor

Tags: xcode, swift3, skcameranode

I have a problem setting up the camera in my Swift 3 project.

[image: This is my scene]

and this is my code

```
cameraNode = childNode(withName: "cameraNode") as! SKCameraNode
view.scene?.camera = cameraNode
```

Can you help me figure out whats wrong here? Even if I move the camera in my scene editor, it won't make any difference in the view of my game.

Answer (score 2):

Set a variable that looks something like this:

```
var GameSceneCamera = SKCameraNode()
```

Keep your first line of code specifically this:

```
cameraNode = childNode(withName: "cameraNode") as! SKCameraNode
```

And delete your second line of code specifically this:

```
view.scene?.camera = cameraNode
```

Then follow these steps:

1. Go to the file GameScene.sks
2. Open the navigation side bar or Navigator (click on the third button from the top right) to open up your assets on the side
3. Click on Scene or the top asset that contains all of these assets
4. Open the side bar on the right or Utilities (click on the first button from the top right)
5. Click on camera and select the node